# Function definition needs clarification

Tags: java

In the code of our professor he is defining his Bubble sort function (and other sorting functions) like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void bubbleSort(T[] array) {
              \_______________________/
                         |
          This is the part I don't understand.
```

He has already defined access modifiers, return type (or lack of it), the function name and it's desired parameters. It doesn't even return an object that can be subject to comparisons, so I find this all a tad confusing. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Start reading here: [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: arg Object must implements the `Comparable` in order to pass `bubbleSort` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [the function] doesn't even return an object that can be subject to comparisons

The signature is defined in a way that the sorted values are placed back into the original array. Method's return type is `void`; the part that you underscored says that

- The method has one generic type parameter called `T`, and that
- This method can be called with an array of any type that implements `Comparable<T>`

In other words, you can call the same method with an array of `String`s, `Integer`s, `Double`s, and any of your own classes that implement `Comparable<T>` interface.

As far as the comparisons go, the function specifies that the elements of the array need to be comparable to each other, because they implement `Comparable<T>`. At this point your sorting function should have everything that you need - namely, the array of items to be sorted, and a way to compare two items to each other. These two conditions are sufficient to implement any sorting algorithm that is based on comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

This definition says that this method can require array of objects which are T type (please see the 2nd usage of `T`), and this T needs to be defined as implementing `Comparable` interface.

In this specific case, the aim of requiring arguments that are implementing this interface is that this method should focus only on implementation of specific sorting algorithm without need to cope with details of ordering and at the same time it allows to sort any types of objects (that are implementing Comparable interface).

For more about generic types and methods please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html and on Comparable interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html